# Hiding page loading

Tags: javascript, html, css

My HTML markup looks like that

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="loading"><img src="core/design/img/load/load.gif" /></div>
<div id="wrap"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to hide whole page loading process with following solution.

CSS Rules:

```
#loading {
    position:fixed; 
    left:0; 
    top:0; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
    background-image:url("img/load/tr.png"); 
    z-index:100;
}
#loading img {position: absolute; margin-left:-110px; margin-top:-9px; left:50%; top:50%}
```

And Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#loading').fadeOut(500);
});
```

Now, the problem is page loads like that:

1. first ugly draft of page (for 1-2 seconds)
2. appears loading div
3. loading whole content
4. disappears loading div

[You can see it in action](http://www.aquastyle.az?lang=en)

I don't understand why loading div appears after 1-2 seconds?

I want to prevent 1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a pretty simple one.

First make sure jQuery is called in your  section.

First, wrap all the content of your page (except the loading div) in a div called

```
<div id="content-wrapper">
    CONTENT HERE
</div>
```

Then using CSS set:

```
#content-wrapper {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Then just make the jQuery into a function like this:

```
$(window).load(function(){

    document.getElementById("content-wrapper").style.visibility="hidden";

    $('#loading').fadeOut(500, function() 
    {
        document.getElementById("content-wrapper").style.visibility="visible";
    });
});
```

and I can see you're using Nivo Slider. Me too ;)

**Edit:** I fixed it, now it works perfectly. (You don't need the onload event in your body tag anymore)

Check out the example here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vGWef/)

Comment: thx for trying to help. But result is the same. clear your cache and try to refresh given page

Comment: Ok. i did it. Please clear cache and reload given page. Everything right, but, loading animation ends fast. It must fade out after full page load. But it ends while loading

Comment: Okay, it's done, now it will work perfectly. Your content will be hidden when you load the page. When it is done loading, image will fade out and your site content will display. Just check my edit.

Comment: read attentively my last comment. loading animation ends long before It must fade out. it ends while loading but must fade out after full page load

Comment: I already fixed that. I changed it so it doesn't do that any more. Now the animation to fade the loading bar only runs when the document is ready

Comment: I found the bug. You need to use $(window).load(function(){ }); instead of $(document).ready(function(){ });

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I looked it up and that is a better option. I'll change my answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Try moving the styles for loading to be inline instead of relying on the full external css file to load. If you look at Google Chrome Developer Tools and the Network tab, or a similar tool, you'll see the content of the page loads first, as expected, but then you have to wait until the external css is loaded and downloaded, and then the referenced image in the css file is loaded. Placing the style inline should assist in getting the loading element to display as soon as it can, or at least sooner.

```
<div id="loading" style="position: fixed;left: 0;top: 0;
 width: 100%;height: 100%;background-image: url(core/design/img/load/tr.png);z-index: 100;"><img src="core/design/img/load/load.gif"></div>
```

Comment: result is the same. clear your cache and try to refresh given page

Comment: @L0rdDEVdem0rt Yes, I can see not a lot has changed. Have you considered hiding the main content so it doesn't flicker like it does? The background image is now loading quicker in the timeline with it being inline, but it appears other elements are loading in as well. Having the main content not displayed inline until it's loaded may help. Just an idea.

Comment: Ok. i did it. Please clear cache and reload given page. Everything right, but, loading animation ends fast. It must fade out after full page load. But it ends while loading

Answer (score 1):

Why not start everything else inside a `<div style="display: none;" id="loaded">`, and then when the loading has finished use `$("#loaded").fadeIn()`?

Comment: First, because i'm going to implement "sticky footer".  http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/  Grouping all divs within new one will mess things. Second, it's not good idea, because page will not load if client browser doesn't support js

Comment: @L0rdDEVdem0rt if client script doesn't work, you'll have bigger problems because the loading screen will be on top of everything. If you're going down the path, go all in.

Comment: Ok. And what about stick footer?

Comment: @L0rdDEVdem0rt if it can't be wrapped in a single div, then just call .fadeIn() on all elements that have to be shown on load, so $("#loaded").fadeIn(); $("#footer").fadeIn(); or something along those lines.

Comment: Ok. i did it. Please clear cache and reload given page. Everything right, but, loading animation ends fast. It must fade out after full page load. But it ends while loading