# The page loading animation for hiding whole page load process ends long before It must fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hiding page loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577413/hiding-page-loading)

I'm using loading animation for hiding whole page load process. but it ends long before It must fade out. it ends while loading but must fade out after full page load

Here is the js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#loading').fadeOut(600, function() 
    {
        $("#wrap").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#footer").fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

HTML markup

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="loading"><img src="core/design/img/load/load.gif" /></div>
<div id="wrap"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to hide whole page loading process with following solution.

CSS Rules:

```
#loading {
    position:fixed; 
    left:0; 
    top:0; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
    background-image:url("img/load/tr.png"); 
    z-index:100;
}
#loading img {position: absolute; margin-left:-110px; margin-top:-9px; left:50%; top:50%}
```

[You can see it in action](http://www.aquastyle.az?lang=en)

Comment: Hey. Try this: http://dancameron.org/code/display-a-loading-image-until-the-page-completes-loading  it's a little different

Comment: Do  you read my question at all? it's the same thing

Comment: $(window).load it's not the same thing of $(document).ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$(window).load(function(){ });` instead of $(document).ready(function(){ });

More info: [$(document).ready vs. $(window).load](http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/)

For users with javascript disabled:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').append('<div id="loading"><img src="core/design/img/load/load.gif" /></div>');
});
$(window).load(function(){ 
    $('#loading').fadeOut(600, function(){
        $("#wrap").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#footer").fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: if javascript is disabled then the image will show but never be hidden, in this case.How about adding some javascript that writes the loading div ?(i mean this one `<div id="loading"><img src="core/design/img/load/load.gif" /></div>`)

Comment: Yes you can do that. See updated answer

Comment: the problem is, now loading appears after whole loading process for 1-2 seconds